# Have an issue while deploying a web site

Tags: php, internal-server-error

First, I apologize for my english level which is not so good.
I'm doing an internship and my task is to continue the development of an intranet website for the company. I've got the code at the beginning of the internship and worked on a local version, with a local webserver and a local database. 
Here comes the time where I deploy my changed version on the company's server and as soon as I've did it, the site that was working until now with the older version display a " Internal server Error 500".
What could it come from and do anyone have a solution ? 
PS : the website is developed with CakePhp.

Comment: Roll back to a previous working commit, then check the error logs on the server. Also check for merge conflicts which have been pushed. Not much we can help.

Comment: Try to get your hands on the http error log file(s).  If on linux/ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can think of that could go wrong.

- Is the database connection valid on the server you deployed too?
- Do you have access rules / url rewrite rules set up (like .htaccess) that prevents files from being loaded after publishing?
- Are the folder permissions on the server the same as on you local machine?

Do you have a logging service implemented on your website?
You might want to look at CakePHP on how to implement logging or [use a librry](https://github.com/cakephp/log) and publish your website again. See if the logs can tell you more.

You could also check the logs of the PHP server on the internal server to see if there's an issue with your code

Comment: I've checked the database connection and It should be okay normally. I actually have a .htaccess in my website but what is it for ?

Comment: Basically the PHP server serves files to the end user. Using .htaccess files you can allow or restrict a user from getting his hands on the files or folders. It's unlikely that your issue resides in .htaccess if you haven't touched them. Just check if there are differences between your local version and the servers' version.

Comment: I've sent the local files directly from my computer with SFTP so there are no differences =/